# How to run StimulusJs with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stimulusjs

I have modal component, and inside the modal I have a form. The modal shows or hides using StimulusJs. When I render the modal component using `turbo_stream`, it executes the stimulus controller and shows it. However, when I am trying to test it using rspec, I see the content gets loaded through `turbo_stream` but it does not visually show it. I always get the following error:

```
Unable to find visible field "user[username]" that is not disabled within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="div" path="/HTML/BODY[1]/TURBO-FRAME[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/DIV[3]">
```

Note that the content is not present on page load, only when a button is clicked it will load the modal component. I know this works because I have an `expect` for it after the button is clicked:

```
expect(page).to have_css("[data-controller='modal']")
```

But then when trying to run

```
fill_in("Username", with: "testing01")
```

I have tried different variations like `find(#).set()` but always with the error that the element is not visible.

```
describe "Username modal", type: :system do
  it "should change the username" do
    visit profile_path
    
    expect(page).to_not have_css("[data-controller='modal']")
    page.find("#change-username").click
    
    expect(page).to_not have_css("[data-controller='modal']")
    fill_in("Username", with: "testing01") # <--- Error mentioned above
    page.find("#submit-change-username").click
    
    expect(page).to have_text("Username changed!")
  end
end
```

This makes me think that StimulusJS is not running. Is there anything I have to do to make sure it runs in rspec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I realized that I needed to precompile the assets for the tests to grab the latest changes. I ended up running: `rails assets:clobber assets:precompile`. Then, I restarted the server, ran the tests gain, and it worked.